# Angular 6 website shows in chrome task manager, 1.3 gb of memory footprint and then 160 mb memory footprint after few seconds

Tags: angular, google-chrome, memory-management, angular6

I'm using Angular 6 and in production, our website starts with 100MB memory footprint and then keeps on increasing to 1.3gb on memory footprint while loading and then it drops to 160mb in a few seconds after the load is complete.

[image: Initial load of image]
[image: Final loading of website]

Can anyone suggest me why is this happening and how to debug this problem?

For this reason, many users are getting *Aw snap* of chrome error when opening the website. I guess users with low RAM are facing this issue.

P.S.: I'm using production build and all the standard production deploy steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the problem and the solution. The problem has got nothing to do with angular but how browsers render the image.

**Problem:** There was an image in a particular page which was having 18000 x 12000 pixel jpg image dimension but the size was ~500kb. Hence when the page was loading then the image was being rendered and that's why the memory foot print was going to 18000*12000*4 byte = ~ 850 MB and rest of the memory consumption is from the angular application and other image rendering.

**Solution:**
Though we made sure that any image is at max 500kb, yet while rendering huge dimension images take a lot more memory, so a new check was put to ensure that the dimension of the image is also monitored.

Comment: Where did you get "*4" in 18000*12000*4 byte = ~ 850 MB?